# UILabel cutting off symbol

Tags: ios, uilabel

**Hello!**

How to get text (string) in my UILabel.
What I mean?
I set a text for my UILabel programmatically. But if my text very large the text don't fit to my label and UILabel cutting off this text.

How I can to check new text with a cutting symbol?

For example:

Source: '**Some Large Text**'

Cutting text: '**Some Large T...**' (need to get this string)

Thanks for response!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the UILabels's property linebreakemode and number of lines:

```
label.numberOfLines       = 2;
label.lineBreakMode       = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

aditionally you might need to set the frame correctly.
cheers

Comment: or UILineBreakModeTailTruncation if you want "Some long text" to read as "Some long..." instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for response, but I want to get the text with a label. for example if now I see text in label 'Some Large T...' and I output in NSLog(@"%@", label.text) I want to see that text (Some Large T...) not a Some Large Text

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100421/uilabel-visible-part-of-text