# How to get the UILabel last index before dots with NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that has static 3 lines. Also it's `lineBreakMode` is `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`.

So if there are the long text that contains over 3 lines, the label will show "..." in the tails.

How can I get the last character or index before "..."? For example:

```
"There are the long long
long long long long long
long long long words ..."
```

I want to know the "s" index.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I locate the CGRect for a substring of text in a UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417776/how-do-i-locate-the-cgrect-for-a-substring-of-text-in-a-uilabel)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417776/how-do-i-locate-the-cgrect-for-a-substring-of-text-in-a-uilabel

Comment: Maybe this can help: [UILabel visible part of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100421/uilabel-visible-part-of-text). This returns `NSRange` of `NSString` that is shown before truncation. Just take the `length` value from range, that gives you the last character to be displayed before `...`.

Comment: @Amar Your comment helps a lot! Thanks!